# Uninstall older version in wix for 4 digits like 1.1.0.1

Tags: wix, installation, uninstallation

while install the higher version than the current installed version, need to uninstall the previous version and install the newer version. And while install the lower version than the current version need to restrict the installation. 
 It is available for 3 digits(1.0.0,2.0.0 etc.,). but i asking for 4 digit version(1.1.0.1,1.1.0.2 etc.,). 
Please any one respond to my question..

Answer (score 5):

This is a design limitation of Windows Installer.  See:

[ProductVersion property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **Remarks**
>
> At least one of the three fields of ProductVersion must change for an
>   upgrade using the Upgrade table. Any update that changes only the
>   package code, but leaves ProductVersion and ProductCode unchanged is
>   called a small update. The three versions fields are provided
>   primarily for convenience. For example, if you want to change
>   ProductVersion, but do not want to change either the major or minor
>   versions, you can change the build version.
>
> Note that Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the
>   product version. If you include a fourth field in your product
>   version, the installer ignores the fourth field.

The WiX [MajorUpgrade Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) has an attribute called AllowSameVersionUpgrades:

> When set to no (the default), installing a product with the same
>   version and upgrade code (but different product code) is allowed and
>   treated by MSI as two products. When set to yes, WiX sets the
>   msidbUpgradeAttributesVersionMaxInclusive attribute, which tells MSI
>   to treat a product with the same version as a major upgrade.
>
> This is useful when two product versions differ only in the fourth
>   version field. MSI specifically ignores that field when comparing
>   product versions, so two products that differ only in the fourth
>   version field are the same product and need this attribute set to yes
>   to be detected.
>
> Note that because MSI ignores the fourth product version field,
>   setting this attribute to yes also allows downgrades when the first
>   three product version fields are identical. For example, product
>   version 1.0.0.1 will "upgrade" 1.0.0.2998 because they're seen as the
>   same version (1.0.0). That could reintroduce serious bugs so the
>   safest choice is to change the first three version fields and omit
>   this attribute to get the default of no.
>
> This attribute cannot be "yes" when AllowDowngrades is also "yes" --
>   AllowDowngrades already allows two products with the same version
>   number to upgrade each other.

Now there is a way to get the best of both worlds. It involves writing a custom action, scheduled after the [FindRelatedProducts action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368600(v=vs.85).aspx), to call the [MsiEnumRelatedProducts function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370103(v=vs.85).aspx) to query MSI and identify installed products that differ only by the fourth field and is less then your new product version.  You then add this to the ActionProperty specified in the upgrade row and let the [RemoveExistingProducts Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197(v=vs.85).aspx) do the rest.

Comment: In other words, excuse me stating what might be obvious, it's irrelevant whether you use WiX or something else to generate the MSI file.

Comment: OpEd: The very first rule of Tao of the Windows Installer (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/01/587990.aspx) stresses the importance of learning Windows Installer. They then mention how people have learned high-level re-packaging tools (AdminStuio and PackageStudio no doubt) without learning MSI and the trouble that follows.  The same could be said today ( nearly 9 years later ) about people who learn just enough WiX to create an MSI but have no concept of Windows Installer and the relationship between it and WiX.

Comment: How do I change the Upgrade table from my custom action?