# Uninstalling 4-digit version during upgrade

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

We create our installation packages with WiX Toolset. I'm trying to enable 4-digit product versioning (like 4.0.0.195, 4.0.0.196 etc). The problem is that when product is upgraded the previous version is not uninstalled.

I am aware of [ProductVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productversion) limitation. And my current approach to the problem is writing a C++ custom action. This action successfully detects the installed product, I have its upgrade code. The custom action is also capable of setting MSI properties through [MsiSetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msisetpropertya). But what do I need to do to force removal of the installed product?

Per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936195/uninstall-older-version-in-wix-for-4-digits-like-1-1-0-1/27942301#27942301) I see that in MSI there is [Upgrade table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgrade-table) that I might have to modify. But how do I do it for running installation? [MsiGetActiveDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msigetactivedatabase) gives a read-only handle. [MsiOpenDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msiopendatabasea) opens MSI files by path.

Am I going the wrong way?

Comment: The 4th tuple is usually a build number and does not install side-by-side (i.e. multiple versions) but does a REPAIR (i.e. install ON TOP OF the previous version.  Our product supports side-by-side to the 2nd tuple (2.1 is a different install than 2.2, but 2.2.2.x installs on top of 2.2.1.y where x & y are just nightly build numbers of those product versions).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are going the wrong way. Use the first three parts of the ProductVersion so upgrades can work correctly.